# static variable being initialized twice

Tags: php, static

I always thought that `static` variables were initialized once only and retained their values until the end of the script. However I came across a bug in my code, where a `div` ID attribute is created by increasing a counter held in a static variable.

Here is a reproduction of the bug:

```
class Node {
    var $child = array();

    public function test () {
        static $var = 0;
        $var++;
        echo $var,"\n";
        foreach ( $this->child as $c )
            $c->test();
    }

    public function add_child ( $c ) {
        $this->child[] = $c;
    }
}
class Tree extends Node {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::add_child( new Node() );
        parent::add_child( new Node() );
    }
}
$tree = new Tree();
$tree->test();
```

The above has 3 calls to `test()` where the expected output should be

> 1 2 3

However, The variable `static $var` is being initialized twice, producing output of:

> 1 1 2

Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Comment: Why don't you use static class members, maybe that would solve your problem. It is an interesting question, but using static function variables inside classes looks quite strange. `class Node { public static $counter = 0; /* … */ }`

Comment: @feeela I agree but I tend to only use class members when that variable would be used in more than one method. It makes reading and debugging easier especially with large classes.

Comment: What's with the downvotes AGAIN??? Is this not an appropriate question?

Comment: @Waldermort Since you are extending the class you are effectively using that variable even throughout multiple classes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the static variable `$var` is being called by `Tree::test()` and the child `Node::test()`.  Not sure of the best way to get around this.  But what I did is make the `Tree::add_child()` add a child object of class `Tree` not class `Node`.

```
class Node {
    var $child = array();

    public function test () {
        static $var = 0;
        $var++;
        echo $var,"\n";
        foreach ( $this->child as $c )
            $c->test();
    }

    public function add_child ( $c ) {
        $this->child[] = $c;
    }
}

class Tree extends Node {
    public static function createInitial() {
        $tree = new Tree();
        $tree->addChild();
        $tree->addChild();
        return $tree;
    }

    public function addChild() {
        parent::add_child( new Tree() );
    }
}

$tree = Tree::createInitial();
$tree->test();
```

Comment: It doesnt look like `there is a static Tree::var property and a static Node::var property`. Where you see defined static properties of both classes ? Op code works properly. Do you even thinking wrong.

Comment: Okay @voodoo417, I misspoke and there is not a static `Tree::var` or `Node::var` property, but `Tree::test()` and `Node::test()` are both called with OP's code..which is what causes the static variable to be initiated twice.

Comment: see manual about defining  static variables inside functions( in this case - in methods)

Comment: @voodoo417, I explicitly said that I am not sure if this is the best solution..but I attempted to explain the problem and fix it directly without modifying OP's logic.  I am still content with my answer, since it is directly explaining and avoiding the problem OP made.

Comment: you didnt modify logic? You added new method and changed almost all code in `Tree`.  You also,as and OP, doesnt understand how statics works in these two cases (static property and local static variable in method).  I advise you to read documentation,too. Good luck!

Comment: @voodoo417 I had to create a new method if I wanted to keep logic the same, otherwise there would be a recursive loop if I did `Tree::__construct() { parent::add_child( new Tree() ); }`.  Anyways, I know how static variables work and when to use them..and sorry you dislike my answer, but the joy of SO is the community so you can get *more than one opinion*.

Comment: Let's stop our discuss. OP asked : why `1 1 2`, but not `1 2 3`? Ok, i set +1 ( will be +2), but your didnt answer on question.

Comment: I forgot to ask: "Anyways, I know how static variables work and when to use them"  You could know because you from start confused static variable inside method with class property. I think, issue is closed.

Answer (score 1):

That is some nasty code. When you are presented with issues like this, it's best to take a step back and consider another way. Otherwise when you come back in 6 months to add a new feature you will want to faceroll the keyboard.

Shot in the dark, looks like [Late Static Binding](https://www.php.net/lsb) (lsb) is at work here. The $tree object you instantiated created two node objects, each of which have a test() method, each of which have a `static $var` bound to them.

$var value per call

```
$tree->test()    $tree->child[0]->test()    $tree->child[1]->test()
1                1                          2
```

Notice that the `$tree->child[1]->test()` call outputs a 2, this is because the `static $var` variable bound itself to the `$tree` object which was already incremented when you made the initial `$tree->test()` call.

I added some output to your original code to demonstrate this point:

```
class Node {

    public $id;

    var $child = array();

    public function test () {

        static $var = 0;

        $var++;

        var_dump(sprintf('Id: %d | Var: %d', $this->id, $var));

        foreach ( $this->child as $key => $c ) {

            var_dump(sprintf('Container Object Id: %d | Child Id: %d | Var: %d', $this->id, $c->id, $var));

            $c->test();
        }
    }

    public function add_child ( $c ) {
        $this->child[] = $c;
    }
}
class Tree extends Node {
    public function __construct() {

        $node1 = new Node;
        $node1->id = 1;

        $node2 = new Node;
        $node2->id = 2;

        parent::add_child( $node1 );
        parent::add_child( $node2 );
    }
}
$tree = new Tree;

$tree->test();

// Output 
//  Conclusion: $var bound itself to $tree during runtime
string 'Id: 0 | Var: 1' (length=14)
string 'Container Object Id: 0 | Child Id: 1 | Var: 1' (length=45)
string 'Id: 1 | Var: 1' (length=14)
string 'Container Object Id: 0 | Child Id: 2 | Var: 1' (length=45)
string 'Id: 2 | Var: 2' (length=14)
```

Comment: Never thought about LSB, but it makes sense. Just tested it on PHP 4, same results though. All I can guess is that the compiler is being invoked twice, once for each of the classes methods.

Comment: The 'static' keyword wasn't introduced until php 5.3.0, are you certain it's php4? php4 doesn't support public, protected, private visibility properties either, so you should get syntax errors if truly php4.

Comment: I used http://writecodeonline.com/ since I don't have it installed locally. So, it probably wasn't an accurate test. I'll install it later and do a true test.